# Angular - Can't assign null to File type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got an interface like this

```js
export interface ReportFiles {
  ReportName: string;
  Log: number;
  MyFile: File;
}
```

And in my component, I declared the object as

```js
export class MyComponent Implements OnInit {
  RF:  ReportFiles = { ReportName: "", Log: 0, MyFile: null }
  ...
  ...
}
```

The error message shows

> 'null' is not assignable to File

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `MyFile` with nullable type.

```js
interface ReportFiles {
  ReportName: string;
  Log: number;
  MyFile?: File | null;
}
```

[Sample Demo on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQA4HspgGLAA2EAzsgN4BQyamOYAcnALYQBcyJYUoA5gNzVkAGSy8OIAK7MARtEE0AsgE8CxAPwc1KAD7IphQoIC+lSsTBo8HWtlzayAXnLo7jFuwBEngDSjxAAw+KtpsBoTG-EA)

Answer (score 1):

We usually don't assign type `any` because it defeats the purpose of type checking but `any` type may be used when type changes are expected.

```
export interface ReportFiles{
  ReportName: string;
  Log: number;
  MyFile: any;
}
```

Seeing your need to initialize a obj RF type of `ReportFiles` I would suggest converting `ReportFiles` and `File` into class objects. But this is optional. If you need/wish to create an instance of perhaps a custom object, whilst getting the benefits of type-checking things such as arguments, return types or generics - a class makes sense. If you’re not creating instances - we have interfaces at our disposal, and their benefit comes from not generating any source code, yet allowing us to somewhat “virtually” type-check our code.